# MySQL Add tag to article if the keyword is in the article title

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, tags

This seems to be a bit out of my league and knowledge of MySQL (I'm not sure if it's even possible with MySQL). So if someone can help it would be much appreciated.

I would like to do the following:

1. Enter/define a keyword e.g. `mercedes`
2. Find all Joomla K2 articles that have that keyword in the title
3. Than to each of those articles assign my keyword `mercedes` as a tag.

Now... There are three tables with relevant columns listed:

#### k2_items

`id`, `title`

#### k2_tags

`id`, `name`, `published` (value 1 is assigned if tag is published)

#### k2_tags_xref

`id`, `tagID`, `itemID`

So, query should select all items from `k2_items` table that have `keyword` in their title, check if `keyword` is already defined as `tag` in `k2_tags`, if not than create a new tag. After that, new `k2_tags_xref` entry should be generated to connect `keyword` tag with K2 article item.

I still didn't have database course on my university so I'm kind of out of my league with this one, and it was supposed to be just a simple touchup for the site I'm developing.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, and I'm sure it'll help community later on.

Thanks!

Comment: @Sadikhasan, is this some chain reaction by you mods or something? Question is very specific and has a nice and short answer as Gordon demonstrated below. What is the problem than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part in SQL is actually pretty easy.  It is simplest if you have a unique index on `k2_tags_xref(tagId, itemId)`.  This has the database check for duplicates.

Then you need to do two things:

- Find all items with the keyword in the title
- Find the `tagId` for the keyword

This results in a query like this:

```
insert into k2_tags_xref(tagId, itemId)
    select t.tagId, i.itemId
    from k2_items i cross join
         (select t.tagId from k2_tags where tag = 'mercedes') t
    where i.title like '%mercedes%';
```

You will also need to put the tag into the tags table, if it is not already there.  But the above query is the basis of the SQL code.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out tomorrow. I'm still on very low level with MySQL. I need to learn properly how to do those joins and what this t. and i. stand for.